# Android relative layout is not showing images correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have created android relative layout , in which , I am trying to show four images in the four sides of the activity with a top bar and background image.

topbar and backgroud image appearing correctly. but , among 4 only 2 images are displaying in the Nexus emulator, remaing 2 images are not visible in the emulator, I have aligned image to left,right in row and left, right in another row.

only left side images are displayed at the center of the emulator, both right side images are not visible.

How can I display all images with equal space on the display. My layout is shown below

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/topbannerimg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/topbanner"
            android:contentDescription="@string/topbar"
            android:src="@drawable/mtnlogotext" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/csrimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topbannerimg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/csrstr"
            android:src="@drawable/customerservice" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/virtualstoreimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topbannerimg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/virstr"
            android:src="@drawable/virtualstore" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mtnstorelocatorimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/csrimg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/storestr"
            android:src="@drawable/storelocater" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mtnviewimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/virtualstoreimg"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mtnstorelocatorimg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/viewstr"
            android:src="@drawable/mtnview" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could You show a drawing of what exactly You want? Do You want to have all four images in the center or do You want the images at the top/bottom/left/right sides?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply , I want 4 images in 2 rows. first 2 images in the first row and second 2 images in the second row. first row first image and second row first image should be aligned [vertically] equally, also first row second image and second row second image should be aligned [vertically] equally.

Comment: Four sided..!? you mean four corners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code just replace icon image with your actual image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff4455"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topbannerimg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#222222"
        android:contentDescription="@string/topbar"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/csrimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topbannerimg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/csrstr"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/virtualstoreimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topbannerimg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/virstr"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mtnstorelocatorimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/storestr"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mtnviewimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/viewstr"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

I'm not sure about layout design, so please upload image what the layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to keep one of the five images on top and then 2 rows, each with 2 images.

I modified your code a bit. Try it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topbannerimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/topbanner"
        android:contentDescription="@string/topbar"
        android:src="@drawable/mtnlogotext" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/topbannerimg" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/csrimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/csrstr"
            android:src="@drawable/customerservice" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/virtualstoreimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/csrimg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/virstr"
            android:src="@drawable/virtualstore" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/row1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mtnstorelocatorimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/csrimg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/storestr"
            android:src="@drawable/storelocater" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mtnviewimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/virtualstoreimg"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mtnstorelocatorimg"
            android:contentDescription="@string/viewstr"
            android:src="@drawable/mtnview" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, still the problem exist, I will try grid layout and post update the status

Answer (score 0):

```
I have used android:layout_width="145dp" and  android:layout_height="100dp" in the images, now the layout is appearing correctly, with images placed in correct rows and columns


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topbannerimg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/topbanner"
        android:contentDescription="@string/topbar"
        android:src="@drawable/mtnlogotext" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/csrimg"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topbannerimg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/csrstr"
        android:src="@drawable/customerservice" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/virtualstoreimg"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topbannerimg"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/csrimg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/virstr"
        android:src="@drawable/virtualstore" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mtnstorelocatorimg"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/csrimg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/storestr"
        android:src="@drawable/storelocater" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mtnviewimg"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/virtualstoreimg"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mtnstorelocatorimg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/viewstr"
        android:src="@drawable/mtnview" />

</RelativeLayout>
```